# Possible Github integration such as code imports?

Tags: feature-request, code

## Github Integration

### Idea

I thought of a new feature that might be helpful. Github integration for questions and answers.

### Examples & Usage

- Code imports in Q&As
- Automatic pull requests from answers
- Automatic issues from Q&As

### Overview

I think that github integration would allow users to solve problems in their code faster.

Comment: Doesn't this discourage users from reducing their code to a minimal example?

Comment: SO answers should stand on their own. "_Code imports in Q&As_" - This is already possible with copy & paste, no need for additional complexity. "_Automatic pull requests from answers_". Huh ? We have comments and edits here for improving stuff. As for automatically making an answer into a Github pull request, i'm not sure we really need something like this. "_Automatic issues from Q&As_". I'm not sure we need this. We can already create issues manually with a minimum amount of effort, and have them exactly as wanted, and anyway, how would this work ? Also, this would discourage making an MCVE.

Answer (score 14):

You're exacerbating the problem.  The issue isn't that there's so much code that it has to live elsewhere; it's that **there's so much code.**

When someone puts a *lot* of code in a question on Stack Overflow, that makes it less likely that someone can look over the question quickly in their precious volunteer time.  Personally, I don't have the luxury of time to dig into a person's project to see what exactly it is that they're seeing, and I would imagine that few others would.

If you're going to put a lot of code on the site, **stop and think** about what it is you're doing.  If the actual problem can be contained to a *few* lines of code, that is **far** better.  If it can't, then the question needs to be *very well* explained.

My fear with this request (outside of it being a liability and a code dump) is that you're going to get reams of code and "it doesn't work, plz help" as the problem statement, which is something we actively want to ward off.

Comment: The general asker's inability to minimize their code is my pet peeve. I completely agree. Most "wall of code" questions minimize by an order of magnitude. Making it easier for people to post walls of code is just wrong. OTOH, I'd like it very much if there was literate programming support for *answers* that could live on github.